# .NET versions in ASP.Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have a asp core web app with

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net452": {}
  },
```

And I have also Class Library (.NET Core).

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0"
      },
      "net452": {}
    }
  }
}
```

The question is, how can I add web app project reference to class library? Should I import some .net framework or use `.net` standard ?

Now I have a error message when I was trying to add reference to class library project.

> The following projects are not supported as references:
>   "webprojectname" has target frameworks that are incompatible with
>   targets in current project "classlibraryprojectname"
>
> "classlibraryprojectname": .NETCoreApp, Version=v1.0 "webprojectname":
>   .NETFramework, Version=v4.5.2

Comment: Did you create an aspnet core project targeting .net framework ? From Visual Studio, you should create a new project with this template : `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core)` rather than `ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)`

Comment: Yes, I created ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework). Can I change this now, or should I create a new project ?

Comment: As per the [docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms), `NetStandard 1.0` maps to `net45`. If you want `net452`, increment your class library to `1.2` or your web app down to `net45`? Alternatively, add `net45` as an additional framework on the class library and allow it to cross-compile. (Former suggestion being preferable)

Comment: It's worth pointing out, your "class library" has been registered as an app given the "frameworks" section you've listed. The class library framework should be 'netstandard1.#', not `netcoreapp1.#`. For example, check out projects on github: [MS Logging Class Library](https://github.com/aspnet/Logging/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions/project.json)

Comment: @Smudge202 I tried to import net461 to Class Library project but now I've another error like: "The dependency Microsoft.CSshartp could not be resolved"

Comment: @Smudge202 Now I can add reference but I got errors which I describe in my previous comment

Comment: Post the latest framework and if possible/present, the dependencies sections for both your web app and your class library.

Comment: @Smudge202 I've edited my post

Comment: Cieja, there should not be `netcoreapp` in your class library frameworks section. Change it to `netstandard1.2` and remove the imports statement.

Comment: @Smudge202 Now I can;t add reference to my web app project. I edited my post

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Updated in accordance with changes to the question.

So I don't keep filling the comments section, your `project.json`'s should look like this:

Web App *(you will also have other dependencies not shown here)*:

```
"dependencies": {
  "YourClassLibrary": "1.0.0-*"
},
"frameworks": {
  "net452": { }
}
```

Class Library:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "dependencies": {
    "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0" 
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.2": { }
  }
}
```

Note: if your class library depends on something higher than `netstandard1.2`, then you will either have to increment the .Net Framework in your web app to match the `NETSTandard` you're using (as per previously [linked docs](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md#mapping-the-net-platform-standard-to-platforms)), or you will need to cross-compile the class library like so:

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",

  "frameworks": {
    "netstandard1.5": {
      "dependencies": {
        "NETStandard.Library": "1.6.0" 
      }
    },
    "net452": { }
  }
}
```

Using the first suggestion, your application produces one assembly for your class library, using this second method your class library will be compiled twice (one for `netstandard1.5`, one for `net452`). When your web app tries to resolve the class library, it realises it can't use `netstandard1.5` (which targets `net462`), so falls back to the `net452` assembly. Note however that using this second option is usually indicative of something not being right with your project structure, and should only be used if you know what you're doing and why (in my opinion).

The [`NETStandard.Library`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/netstandard.library) dependency shown is essential a NuGet *bundle* that pulls down the necessary CoreFX packages. If you get errors like "Cannot find Microsoft.CSharp" it's usually because you haven't pulled down the default packages. You can instead pull down only the CoreFX packages you want, such as [`System.Collections`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Collections/) but this is a more advanced technique.

Hopefully that helps clear things up?

Comment: Now I got an error with "myclasslibraryprojectname": "1.0.0-*"  -> The dependency "myclasslibraryproject >= 1.0.0-* could not be resolved

Comment: If you've made a lot of changes like we've discussed, Visual Studio sometimes gets a little confused. Close and re-open the solution. If that doesn't resolve the issue, delete the `project.lock.json` files and let them regenerate (delete the class library lock file first, then the web app lock file). Whilst .NET Core is RTM, the tooling is still in Preview unfortunately.

Comment: @Cieja I noticed you updated your question, which I assume was a copy paste of my own. In turn, I noticed I was missing a bracer which I've now corrected in the third code block. You'll need to do the same. I recommend against using that approach until you understand how this stuff works a little better (no reason my first suggestion shouldn't work if you follow the advice about reopening/deleting lock files).